# WP get_terms - two taxonomies, one with specified term

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm trying to figure out one topic, I have the impression that the solution is child's play, but somehow I don't know how to end it. To the point - I have code related to get_terms:

```
<?PHP

$terms = get_terms([
                'taxonomy' => array('job-category'),
                'hide_empty' => true,
                'orderby'  => 'count',
                'order' => 'DESC', 
]);
 
 usort( $terms, function( $a, $b ) {
                $a_ste = (int) get_term_meta( $a->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true );
                $b_ste = (int) get_term_meta( $b->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true );
            
                if ($a_ste == $b_ste) return 0;
                return ($a_ste < $b_ste) ? -1 : 1;
            } );
 
 
              if ($terms) { //categories exists
                foreach ($terms as $category) { ?>
 
                    <h2 class="category-title">
                      <?= $category->name ?>
                    </h2>
<?PHP endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Everything works ok. I fetch the terms from the job-category taxonomy and display them.

The issue is that I want these displayed job-category terms to be only those that have very specific terms ("germany") given in a different taxonomy (job-country). How to get it? in other loops like wp_query I mostly used tax_query. But here I need/want to stick to get_terms...

So just to sum up - I'm looking for a way to use get_terms with:

```
- job-category (all terms)
- job-country (only term "germany")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the _$args['taxonomy']_ and the _$args['include']_ parameters of [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)?

Comment: yes i've did. And i didnt find anything that works :(

Answer (score 2):

To get terms from (job-category) based on a term from (job-country), you have to see which posts are tagged with that specific term and then find out which job-category terms are assigned to those posts.

Use WP_Query with object_ids in get_terms to get the post IDs, you can utilize the object_ids parameter in get_terms to fetch the job-category terms associated with these posts.

For example:

```
<?PHP
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type', // Replace with your post type 
if not 'post'
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job-country',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'germany'
        ),
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids' // only return post IDs
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$post_ids = $query->posts;

$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => array('job-category'),
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'object_ids' => $post_ids
]);

usort($terms, ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve only the 'job-category' terms that are associated with the 'germany' term in the 'job-country' taxonomy using `get_terms`, you can't directly filter by taxonomy terms as you would with `WP_Query`. However, you can achieve this by first getting the 'germany' term ID from the 'job-country' taxonomy and then using it to filter the 'job-category' terms. Here's how you can do it:

```php
<?php
// Get the 'germany' term ID from the 'job-country' taxonomy
$germany_term = get_term_by('slug', 'germany', 'job-country');
$germany_term_id = $germany_term->term_id;

// Now, use the term ID to filter 'job-category' terms
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'job-country', // This is assuming you have a custom field for 'job-country'
            'value' => $germany_term_id,
        ],
    ],
]);

usort($terms, function ($a, $b) {
    $a_ste = (int) get_term_meta($a->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true);
    $b_ste = (int) get_term_meta($b->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true);

    if ($a_ste == $b_ste) return 0;
    return ($a_ste < $b_ste) ? -1 : 1;
});

if ($terms) { //categories exist
    foreach ($terms as $category) { ?>
        <h2 class="category-title">
            <?= $category->name ?>
        </h2>
    <?php endforeach;
}
?>
```

In this code, we first obtain the 'germany' term ID from the 'job-country' taxonomy and then use it in the `meta_query` parameter to filter the 'job-category' terms. This way, you'll only get 'job-category' terms that are associated with 'germany' in the 'job-country' taxonomy. Make sure to replace `'job-country'` and `'job-country'` with your actual taxonomy and custom field names as needed.

Comment: unfortunately this code doesn't work as expected. My initial code was grouping posts with specific taxonomy terms (category1->post a, post b etc). Your code do not show any of the taxonomy terms, just a list of all posts and without matching both taxonomies

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a loop within the conditional for the terms in your code, similar to the one below, to specify the job-country just below the `usort()`. For example:

```php
if ($terms) {
    $specific_terms = array();

    foreach ($terms as $category) {
        $term_has_relationship = false;
        $country_relationship = get_term_meta($category->term_id);
        foreach($country_relationship as $key=>$val){ 
            if ($val[0] === 'Germany') {
                $term_has_relationship = true;
            }
        }
        if ($term_has_relationship) {
            // If the term is related to Germany, add it to the array
            $specific_terms[] = $category;
        }
    }
    // Now, you have the terms of 'job-category' that have a relationship with 'Germany' in 'job-country'
    // Loop through the specific terms
    foreach ($specific_terms as $category) {
        ?>
        <h2 class="category-title">
            <?= $category->name ?>
        </h2>
  <?php endforeach;endif;
  ?>
```

From what I understand of your question, I think this would help.

You can also debug the code to analyze the responses more effectively in WordPress.

Open the wp-config.php file. And insert the following code into the file:

```
// Enable debug mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
// Store logs in /wp-content/debug.log
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

In the above code, in addition to enabling debugging, all encountered errors are also stored in a log file. The file is located at wp-content/debug.log.

If you are working on a live installation, or your code is reporting a lot of bugs, you should also set the following to false in your wp-config.php file,

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

this will switch off the error logging on the front-end and only log them in the debug.log file.

Comment: It returns no posts at all

Comment: I edited the previous resolution to search for all terms and then filter by searched in the conditional just to validate if there is a relationship in the taxonymy informed by you.

Also enable logs and use var_dump() to validate method returns and better analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `get_terms()` does not support `tax_query` like `WP_Query` does. However, you can achieve your goal by using `WP_Query` to get the posts that have the specific term in the 'job-country' taxonomy and then use `wp_list_pluck()` to get the 'job-category' terms from those posts.

Here is a sample, untested but I believe will work as expected. Be sure to check your post type and update as needed.

```
<?php
// Get posts that have the 'germany' term in the 'job-country' taxonomy
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post', // replace with your post type, i.e. job, or listing if not post
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'job-country',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'germany',
        ],
    ],
]);

// Get the 'job-category' terms from those posts
$terms = [];
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'job-category');
        if (!empty($post_terms) && !is_wp_error($post_terms)) {
            $terms = array_merge($terms, $post_terms);
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

// Remove duplicate terms
$terms = array_unique($terms, SORT_REGULAR);

// Sort the terms
usort($terms, function($a, $b) {
    $a_ste = (int) get_term_meta($a->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true);
    $b_ste = (int) get_term_meta($b->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true);

    if ($a_ste == $b_ste) return 0;
    return ($a_ste < $b_ste) ? -1 : 1;
});

// Display the terms
if (!empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $category) { ?>
        <h2 class="category-title">
            <?= $category->name ?>
        </h2>
    <?php }
}
?>
```

This code first gets all the posts that have the 'germany' term in the 'job-country' taxonomy. Then it gets the 'job-category' terms from those posts. After that, it removes any duplicate terms and sorts the terms. Finally, it displays the terms.